# How to prevent Eclipse from making sounds

Tags: eclipse

You'll probably consider this as a stupid question, but here goes:

When I'm using `Eclipse`'s **Find** (within an editor page) and whenever eclipse reaches the end of the document it '*dings*'. 
I want to control that '*ding*' in some way - change its sound, volume or better yet - prevent it altogether.

I couldn't find a way to do it in the `Preferences` screen. Any idea?

Comment: I would have thought that was a system sound, not an eclipse specific thing.  Try disabling system sounds and see if that helps.  Not really a question for here though

Comment: @Sam Holder - System Sounds don't occur on their own, eclipse has to do something to tell the system to produce a sound. But there is no way to control it and tell eclipse specifically not to produce sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Windows 7, you can decide the sound volume per application. Just leave your Eclipse open, check the sound volume within your system tray and mute Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - I am using windows 7, and this is what I needed. Although `Eclipse` is not in the list of apps - it is effected by the `System Sounds` section so I could turn it off/lower its volume.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK **there is no such preference in Eclipse**. In fact, in Ubuntu there is no sound in either situation.

You will have to prevent the sound from within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to kill the 'ding' (it even works for all your applications!):

1. Go to the Windows "Control Panel" -> "Sounds and Audio Devices"
2. Select Tab "Sounds"
3. Select Program event "Default Beep"
4. Change the sound to "(None)"
5. Click on the Apply button and enjoy the silence

Edwin

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 go to Settings -> Sound -> App volume device preferences -> tune the System sounds.

[image: App volume device preferences]